# The FileExistsError when I try to create the virtualenv for a specific project in docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I created a container with the python image and when I try to create the `virtualenv` for a specific project I get the error message:

```
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/usr/local/bin/python' -> '/ui-automation/bin/python'
```

The command that I'm executing is:

```
docker exec 07266399997 sh -c 'cd ui-automation && virtualenv .'
```

Comment: Do you copy the virtual environment into your `/ui-automation/`? And so the file exist in the venv folder?

Comment: @Keijack yes, my problem was that I copied the virtual environment into my `/ui-automation/` thank you for your help

Comment: For many use cases in Docker you don't need a virtual environment at all.  In your Dockerfile, `RUN pip install` directly to install dependencies into the "system" Python; since it's inside an image it will still be isolated from other Pythons.